# .NET Verbatim with parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a string using verbatim & parameters, but cannot get it to work, keep getting malformed string.

```
var query = string.Format(@"
query {
    projects (hubId: ""{0}"") {
        results {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}", hubId)
```

The `hubId` needs to be in quotes, and it's just easier to have as a verbatim (the queries can get long)

Comment: You don’t need `String.Format` and you’re missing the leading `$` token - and you need to double-up curly braces: `$@“query {{ etc, hubId: {hubId} }}”;`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use string interpolation as such:

```cs
var query = $@"
query {{
    projects (hubId: ""{hubId}"") {{
        results {{
            id
            name
        }}
    }}
}}";
```

If you're using C# 11, which introduces multiple `$` and `"""`, you can:

```cs
var query = $$"""
query {
    projects (hubId: "{{hubId}}") {
        results {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}""";
```

The number of `$` determine the number of `{` and `}` needed to wrap the variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#raw-string-literals

If you're set on using `string.Format()`, you'll need to double your braces as well:

```cs
var query = string.Format(@"
query {{
    projects (hubId: ""{0}"") {{
        results {{
            id
            name
        }}
    }}
}}", hubId);
```

Comment: the C# 11 should be better, I think. I'm trying to avoid the double braces as those queries are changing... thanks!

Comment: The one downside to interpolated strings is they always use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which may not be desirable in many situations. Unfortunately you have to use some ugly syntax to force `InvariantCulture` or a custom provider. 2 steps forward 1 step back. Ugh. It was soooo close to being a perfect language feature.

Comment: @Dai Agreed, I wish there was better support for culture. Are you referring to the `FormattableString.Invariant($"some value {42:C}")` method?

Comment: @nullforce Yeah, it's super-annoying that they made a special-carve out so that `FormattableString` literals _cannot_ be targeted by extension-methods - that's some _arbitrary levels of cruelty_ right there - I wouldn't be complaining if I could just do `$"Hi {bob}".Inv()` or similar - I really hate having to dart my eyes from the end of an expression back to the leftmost because someone wrapped an expression in an awkward method call or cast expression.